# Shell Script pass Parameter inside a String

Tags: string, shell, parameters

how can I pass a parameter to a shell script that is a longer string with spaces and "-"? Here is what I currently have:

```
/usr/test.sh -g filesystem -q -p "-p \"/usr/\" -s \"some intern string\" -q"
```

The **test.sh** script recognizes two `-p`, two `-q` and some other things, that are not right. But the value behind the first `-p` should be one large string: `-p "/usr/" -s "some intern string" -q`

What is my mistake?

Thanks for any help,
greetings,
Chriss

Comment: This really smells like an XY problem. What are you **doing** with `"${flags[parameter]}"` ? Once you concatenate a string with spaces into another string with spaces, there's no reliable way to extract the original string.

Comment: Also, you're adding extra quotes into the values here:     `wasteParameter+=("\"$arg\"")`

Comment: @glennjackman I am afraid, but the script does not run to this point. It interrupts at the point `if [ $? != 0 ] ; then` with the error, that it found some not allowed parameter. So there must be a problem with `getopt` I guess.

Answer (score 1):

One way of seeing what is being passed is running `printf "<<%s>>\n" yourcommand`, which will print each individual argument on a line surrounded by `<<..>>` for easy disambiguation:

```
$ printf "<<%s>>\n" /usr/test.sh -g filesystem -q -p "-p \"/usr/\" -s \"some intern string\" -q"
<</usr/test.sh>>
<<-g>>
<<filesystem>>
<<-q>>
<<-p>>
<<-p "/usr/" -s "some intern string" -q>>
```

As you can see, the argument to `-p` is indeed the string `-p "/usr/" -s "some intern string" -q`.

If `test.sh` doesn't work, it's a bug in `test.sh`, not in this invocation.

Comment: I added the important part out of my `test.sh` file and I really hope, you can explain my what I did wrong here. and sorry for stealing your time :(

Comment: @christopher2007 That's a separate question, but what you pasted from `test.sh` is fine and if you put `printf "<<%s>>\n" "${flags[parameter]}"` at the end you get the expected value of `<<-p "/usr/" -s "some intern string" -q>>`

Comment: I am afraid, but the script does not run to this point. It interrupts at the point `if [ $? != 0 ] ; then` with the error, that it found some not allowed parameter. But as you mentioned, with `printf "<<%s>>\n" /usr/test.sh -g filesystem -q -p "-p \"/usr/\" -s \"some intern string\" -q"` the correct parts are displayed. Is there something wrong with my `getopt`?